# Show that $ \left\{ \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k) \right\}=\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}-1 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to prove the following:
$$ \left\{ \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k) \right\}=\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}-1 $$
where $ \{ x \} $ is the [fractional part](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html) of $x$.

In fact, this is an abuse of notation, since actually the series doesn't converge. What it does is oscillate between two values that are exactly an integer apart (as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Ck%2B1%5DDivide%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5B2%2C2k%5D-1%5C%2841%29%2CPower%5B2%2C%5C%2840%292k-1%5C%2841%29%5D%5Dzeta%5C%2840%292k%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C101%7D%5D)), so they have the same fractional part, hence the notation. It would have been more correct to write:
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\left\{\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k) \right\}=\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$
However, I attacked the problem in several ways, including:

1. using $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$ and then exchanging the order of summation we get:
   $$\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k)=\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2k}}=$$
   $$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}$$
   which doesn't seem much easier.
2. using $\zeta(2s)=\frac{(-1)^{s+1}B_{2s}(2\pi)^{2s}}{2(2n)!}$:
   $$\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k)=\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{(2^{2k}-1)B_{2k}\pi^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
   but I don't recognise this to be a known sum with Bernoulli numbers.

Plus notice the fact that
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{i}{2}\left[\psi\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right)- \psi\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right) \right]$$
which didn't help me at all but perhaps it can be useful. The real problems are that all these sums are not converging, but rather oscillating, and it's not clear how and when to use the fractional part to get the desired result. Maybe using some integral representation of the zeta function?

Any ideas?

Comment: Wait, what am I even doing. I didn't even notice the curly braces. My bad. I'm deleting my previous comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us instead consider the convergent series $$S:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k)-2\right)=2+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\left(\zeta(2k)-1\right)-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\zeta(2k)}{2^{2k}}$$ which converges by the alternating series test.

Now use the standard series representation $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ for $\Re(s)>1$ to arrive at
\begin{align*}S&=2+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n^{2k}}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2^{2k}n^{2k}}
\\ &=2+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2+1}
\\ &=1+\pi\coth(\pi)-\frac{\pi}{2}\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\\ &=1+\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
where the second equality follows from the fact that the sums above are infinite geometric series, and the third equality follows through say the Mittag-Leffler expansion of $\coth(z)$, through a digamma function argument, through a Poisson summation formula argument, etc.

Now notice that since $2\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}=1-(-1)^n$ alternates between $0$ and $2$ depending on the parity of $n$, it contributes no fractional part, meaning \begin{align*}\lim_{N\to\infty}\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{N}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k)\right\}&=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{2^{2k}-1}{2^{2k-1}}\zeta(2k)-2\right)\right\}
\\ &=\left\{\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1\right\}
\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-1,
\end{align*}
as was to be shown. $\square$

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. Do you know any link with some list of the Mittag-Leffler expansions? On wikipedia there are no hyperbolic functions...

Comment: @Zima Indeed, the expansions are just of the normal trigonometric functions which have poles on the real axis. Simply take $$\cot(z)=\frac{1}{z} + 2z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^2-(n\pi)^2}$$ andt use the fact that $i\cot(iz)=\coth(z)$.